# Javascript?:How to dynamically add text inputs/form fields to a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I am building a web form where there is a list of inputs. So far, so good.

However, how can I add a link/button to add say another 5 fields to the list. eg:

```
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>

<a href="" onclick="">Add 10 more fields</a>
```

I have looked through many similar q's on this site, however none seem to describe how to add multiple fields.

Thanks for any help,

Harley

**EDIT: Thanks all for help, looks like jquery append is the way to go.
However I appreciate the alternative that does not use jquery.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  $("#anyDiv").html('<input id="id1"/>');
```

....

```
 $("#anyDiv").append('<input id="id2"/>');
```

Comment: @harley : Welcome .. That Tick and Upvote just made me cross 1K.. Enjoying SO :)

Comment: @harley - I just discovered today that $("body").append(someContent) does not work in IE7 while $(someContent).appendTo("body") does work.  Quirky I know, but it reminded about this question and thought I'd come back and update it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [**js fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jarekb84/pNVmf/) showing the example of adding 10 inputs using jQuery's [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function. I suggest only doing one addition per click as in user1301840's example though.

**HTML**

```
<div id="inputList"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add 10 Inputs" id="addInputs" />​
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#addInputs').click(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $('#inputList').append('<input type="text" />');

    }
});​
```

Comment: Sorry, another question- how could I make them into a list so they all sit on the left?

Comment: @harley: You could use `display: block` for the `input`s. Then each would have its own line.

Comment: Pay attention when copying code, I've gone crazy because of a invisible character at the end of the block.

Answer (score 2):

While you already have answers, I thought I'd try and provide a non-jQuery solution:

```
function addInput(insertAt, formEl, num, inputType, defaultVal) {
    console.log(formEl);
    if (!formEl) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        num = num ? num : 5;
        var fieldset = document.createElement('fieldset'),
            newInput;
        for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            newInput = document.createElement('input');
            newInput.value = defaultVal || '';
            newInput.type = inputType || 'text';
            fieldset.appendChild(newInput);
        }
        formEl.insertBefore(fieldset, insertAt);
    }
}

var formEl = document.getElementById('theForm'),
    aElem = document.getElementById('aElement');

if (window.addEventListener) {
    // up to date browsers
    aElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
        addInput(this, formEl, 10);
    }, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    // legacy IE, <9
    aElement.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
        addInput(this, formEl);
    });
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DPwmJ/).

I don't have IE to test, but the above *should* work with IE < 9 using the `attachEvent` fall-back, and >= 9, I think, implements the standard `addEventListener()`.

References:

- [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).
- [`attachEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertBefore).

Comment: You're perfectly welcome; hopefully it'll be of some use to you, or others. =)

Comment: I think I'm going to use the jquery append. I'll use your solution I I ever have to do this again with using the library!

Answer (score 1):

try use the JQuery [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function

```
$("a").click(function(e){
 $("form").append("<input />");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, jquery is the way to go here.

```
$("<input type='text'>").appendTo("#someContainer");
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The following example add input box at click a link:

```
<div id="start">
    <input/><br/><br/>
</div> 
<a href="#" id="box">Add more fields</a>
```

---

```
$("#box").click(function(){
    var add="";
    add+='<input/>'+'<br/>'+'</br/>';
    $("#start").append(add);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var counter = 1;
    var limit = 3;
    function addInput(divName) {

        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<br><input type='text' name='myInputs" + counter + "'> <input type='text' name='myInputs" + counter + "'> <select><option value='88888'>888888888</option></select>";
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        counter++;
    }
</script>
```

```
<form method="POST">
    <div id="dynamicInput">

        <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onclick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
</form>
```

Comment: Adding some explanation in English would be great