# PHP/Javascript: Remembering state of form/form fields with cookies

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, cookies

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474563/javascripthow-to-dynamically-add-text-inputs-form-fields-to-a-html-form) question, I found out how to dynamically add form fields.

Now, how can I set a cookie to remember the amount of form fields that were generated, and their content?

eg. First visit, user types this:

```
Input one
Input two
Input three
```

Then he/she visits the page again. There are 3 form fields, containg Input one, Input two and Input 3.

Is this possible using a server/client side solution?

Thanks a lot,

Harley

Comment: You might want to take a look at [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: Looking... Gotta go to bed!! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that the input textfield class is "textfield1" -

This snippet will capture the data into a cookie when the value is modified

```
  $(".textfield1").change(function() {
       $.cookie("textfield1", $(".textfield1").val(), {expires: 7});
  });
```

This snippet will read the cookie data and populate the field on page load -

```
  $(".textfield1").val( $.cookie("textfield1") );
```

Put both these snippets inside $(document).ready(function(){ }); and you are good to go !

Answer (score 0):

there is a useful plugin of jquery "[Jquery Populate](http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html)" you can store your json in cookie/session and use it to fill your forms.